# Create submenu page and create copy of add-new users in wordpress admin dashboard

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-admin

I have created menu and sub menu in WordPress admin dashboard. Now I want to create same page as add-new user for other role users to register. How can I do that ? I have to copy same as add-new-user.

Thanks,

Comment: You could take a look, on how wordpress did it  - /wp-admin/user-new.php

Comment: if you want exact copy, you might even be able to just include it.

Comment: I tried the same as of wp-admin/usr-new.php but it didnt worked. So wondering if any other specific solution.

Comment: well it wouldn't work to just copy the code :) the paths for the requirements would be wrong. - like the first line `require_once( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/admin.php' );` would be a different path in your own plugin/file

Comment: I will try doing this by including in theme file.

Comment: @RakhiPrajapati do not edit the core WP files. Have you read over: https://codex.wordpress.org/Adding_Administration_Menus. Possible duplicate of: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/91693/adding-a-custom-admin-page